# Replace a string in C without string.h library

Tags: c, string

I want to make a function which will replace two strings without using `<string.h>` library. In order to achieve that, I used 6 manually written functions which are together achieving this task.
I have a small problem with this code, this doesn't check if string which will be replaced is word which is completely equal to replacing string.

For example:

```
char s[] = "Why is ostring in C so hard",
     change_what[] = "string",
     into_what[] = "pointers";
```

OUTPUT should be:

```
"Why is ostring in C so hard"
```

Because `"ostring"` is not completely equal to `"string"`.

My output is:

```
"Why are opointers in C so hard"
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare(char *x, char *y)
{
    while (*x != '\0' || *y != '\0')
    {
        if (*x == *y)
        {
            x++;
            y++;
        }
        // if they are not equal
        else if ((*x == '\0' && *y != '\0') || (*x != '\0' && *y == '\0') ||
                 *x != *y)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int lenght(char *a)
{
    char *b;
    for (b = a; *a; a++)
        ;
    return a - b;
}

char *substring(char *main_string, char *substring) {
    while (*main_string != '\0') {
        char *p = main_string;
        char *q = substring;
        while (*p++ == *q++) {
            if (*p == ' ' || *p == '\0')
               if (*q == '\0') {
                   return main_string;
            }
        }
        main_string++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void replace_string_add(char *s, char *change_what, char *into_what,
                        int shift)
{
    char *i_pointer = into_what;
    char *c_pointer = change_what;
    char *position = substring(s, change_what);
    while (position != NULL)
    {
        char *end = position;
        while (*end != '\0')
        {
            end++;
        }
        while (end > position)
        {
            *(end + shift) = *end;
            end--;
        }
        while (*into_what != '\0')
        {
            *position++ = *into_what++;
        }
        position = substring(s, change_what);
        into_what = i_pointer;
        change_what = c_pointer;
    }
}

void replace_string_remove(char *s, char *change_what, char *into_what,
                           int shift)
{
    char *i_pointer = into_what;
    char *c_pointer = change_what;
    char *position = substring(s, change_what);
    while (position != NULL)
    {
        char *temp = position;
        while (*(temp + shift) != '\0')
        {
            *temp = *(temp + shift);
            temp++;
        }
        *temp = '\0';
        while (*into_what != '\0')
        {
            *position++ = *into_what++;
        }
        position = substring(s, change_what);
        into_what = i_pointer;
        change_what = c_pointer;
    }
}

void replace_string(char *s, char *change_what, char *into_what)
{
    int shift = lenght(into_what) - lenght(change_what);
    if (compare(change_what, into_what) == 0)
    {
        if (shift >= 0)
        {
            replace_string_add(s, change_what, into_what, shift);
        }
        else
        {
            replace_string_remove(s, change_what, into_what, -shift);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Why is ostring in C so hard",
         change_what[] = "string",
         into_what[] = "pointers";
    replace_string(s, change_what, into_what);
    printf("\"%s\"", s);
    return 0;
}
```

If string is `"Why is strings in C so hard"` program would work correct because it checks if last characters are `' '` or `'\0'`.

`"Why is ostring in C so hard"` wouldn't work, because it doesn't check first character.
Could you help me modify this code to check also first character?

- Note: auxiliary strings and dynamic allocation are not allowed

Comment: `string.h` is not a library.  It is a header which declares functions that are in the standard library.

Comment: "strings" is not completely equal to "string", but "string" is completely equal to "string" and that is the substring that was found. You need to define the delimiting conditions for the beginning and end of potentially matching substrings.

Comment: So it would appear that you're not actually reading a word, but substituting matches. A word is defined as a series of characters that are delimited by either a space (' ') or a null value.

Comment: If dynamic allocation is not allowed, among other changes you'll want to do something like `char s[1024]="Why are strings in C so hard"` to avoid overflowing the buffer.  And add bounds checking.

Comment: *"Note: auxiliary strings and dynamic allocation are not allowed"* - well that's going to come back to bite you hard then, because `s` in `main` has space for *exactly*  29 characters including the terminator, your 'replacement' will result in a string 30 characters long including the terminator. E.g. you're trying to stuff 30 pounds of nuts in a 29 pound bag. You need to change `s` to allow for the extra required space.

Comment: The output `Why are pointerss in C so hard` is a correct replacement of the substring `string` with the string `pointers`, but it is also a manifestation of undefined behavior.  That will not be the output that you see on all machines.  (This is the point being made in @WhozCraig and my own previous comment.)

Comment: thank you very much, could you help me modify my substring function to check if word is equal, not substring?

Comment: I don't see any good reason to avoid `string.h` header file, it's just core C (don't hate it).

Comment: Regarding your question, you can do it. I have faith. Just ensure that the first character *after* your prospect source sequence of chars you think is a viable match, `string` in this case, is either whitespace or the terminator. if it is, then it matches. If it is neither of those then it must be some `stringX`, where `X` is some non-whitespace, non-terminator, and therefore not a perfect match to `string`.

Comment: Good engineering is to question if the specification makes sense before writing a single line of code. "Note: auxiliary strings and dynamic allocation are not allowed" seems to imply in-place substitution, but there isn't enough memory to do that. The answer is: it can't be done, not unless the requirements are changed.

Comment: I edited my code and fixed my substring function, but I have wrong output, could you help me fix it?

Comment: I just need to check first character, could anyone explain how to do that?

Comment: You said "I want to make a function", but I think you mean, "My homework assignment is to make a function".  Can you tell us what your homework assignment says about the definition of the "words" or "tokens" you're supposed to replace?  What should it do with `"Why is,string,in C so hard"`?

Comment: word is array of characters separated with space, with `"Why is,string,in C so hard"` it should do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has multiple issues:

- there is a lot of redundant code in the `compare` function. You can simplify it as:

  ```
  int compare(const char *x, const char *y) {
      while (*x != '\0' || *y != '\0') {
          if (*x == *y) {
              x++;
              y++;
          } else {
              return 0;
          }
      }
      return 1;
  }
  ```

  or even further:

  ```
  int compare(const char *x, const char *y) {
      while (*x++ == *y++) {
          if (x[-1] == '\0')
              return 1;
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- the `lenght` function should be named `length`
- `substring` checks for a space after the end of the substring, but does not check for a space before the start. It also has undefined behavior if the substring matches the end of the `main_string` because characters beyond the null terminator will be accessed. Here is a modified version:

  ```
  char *substring(char *main_string, const char *substring) {
      char *p = main_string;
      char last = ' ';
      while (*p != '\0') {
          if (last == ' ') {
              size_t i = 0;
              while (substring[i] != '\0' && p[i] == substring[i]) {
                  i++;
              }
              if (substring[i] == '\0' && (p[i] == ' ' || p[i] == '\0')) {
                  return p;
              }
          }
          last = *p++;
      }
      return NULL;
  }
  ```
- in `replace_string_add`  and `replace_string_remove`, `c_pointer` is useless and it would be less confusing to use `i_pointer` to copy the replacement than modify `into_what` and restore it.

Note also that the `main_string` argument must have enough space for the replacements, which would not be the case in the example if the `change_what` string was `"ostring"`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare(const char *x, const char *y) {
    while (*x++ == *y++) {
        if (x[-1] == '\0')
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int length(const char *a) {
    const char *b;
    for (b = a; *a; a++)
        continue;
    return a - b;
}

char *substring(char *main_string, const char *substring, int len) {
    char *p = main_string;
    char last = ' ';
    while (*p != '\0') {
        if (last == ' ') {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < len && p[i] == substring[i]) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i == len && (p[i] == ' ' || p[i] == '\0')) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        last = *p++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *replace_string(char *s, const char *change_what, const char *into_what) {
    int what_len = length(change_what);
    int into_len = length(into_what);
    int shift = into_len - what_len;
    int i;
    char *pos = s;

    if (shift == 0 && compare(change_what, into_what))
        return s;

    while (*pos && (pos = substring(pos, change_what, what_len)) != NULL) {
        if (shift > 0) {
            for (i = length(pos); i >= what_len; i--) {
                pos[i + shift] = pos[i];
            }
        } else
        if (shift < 0) {
            for (i = into_len; ((pos[i] = pos[i - shift]) != '\0'; i++) {
                continue;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < into_len; i++) {
            *pos++ = into_what[i];
        }
        if (*pos == ' ') {
            pos++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char s[100] = "Why is ostring in C so hard";
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "string", "pointer"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "ostring", "pointers"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "is", "are"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "hard", "cool"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "pointers", "strings"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "in C", ""));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "", "in C++ not"));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", replace_string(s, "", ""));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"Why is ostring in C so hard"
"Why is pointers in C so hard"
"Why are pointers in C so hard"
"Why are pointers in C so cool"
"Why are strings in C so cool"
"Why are strings  so cool"
"Why are strings in C++ not so cool"
"Why are strings in C++ not so cool"
```

Comment: you made it so simple, thank you very much

Comment: Learn by example! Try and optimize this case: replacing `aa` with `a` in a string with many occurrences of `aa` will make many intermediary copies... make it run in **O(n)** time by using 2 pointers: one for reading and one for writing.

Answer (score 0):

ok clear, I think it's easier to use a string tokenizer for this.
The following code first copies s into s2 and then puts a '\0' at every space and keeps track of how many words there are. the first for loop.
Then clear out s and loop through s2 stopping at every '\0' sentinel and check if every word equals your replace word.
If it matches copy back the replace word otherwise the original word.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void cat(char *d, char *s)
{
    char *p;
    for (p = d; *p; p++);
    
    for (char *p2 = s; *p2;)
      *p++ = *p2++;
    *p = 0;
}

static int cmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;
    
    while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2)
    {
        p1++;
        p2++;
    }

    if (*p1 == 0 && *p2 == 0) return 0;
    
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char s[100]="Why are strings in C so hard",change_what[]="strings", into_what[]="pointers";
    
    char s2[100];
    
    for (char *p = s, *p2 = s2; *p2=*p; p++, p2++);
    
    int countwords = 0;
    
    for (char *p = s2; *p; p++)
       if (*p == ' ') { *p = '\0'; countwords++; }

    int current = 0;
    
    char *s3 = s2;
    *s = '\0';
    
    while (current <= countwords)
    {
        char *p = s3;
        for (; *p; p++);
        
        if (cmp(s3, change_what) == 0)
            cat(s, into_what);
        else
            cat(s, s3);
            
        cat(s, " ");
            
        s3 = p + 1;

        current++;
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Use the string.h library" is not a great answer to the question "Replace a string in C without string.h library". Obviously it can be made more elegant by using all these functions, but the task here rather seems to be understanding of how the string.h functions are implemented underneath the hood. So this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: the point was the tokenizing, not the compare and concat functions but anyway changed it

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen You used auxiliary string which is not allowed

Comment: your code adds one extra space on the end, try it with `printf("\"%s\"", s);`